# How can date and timestamp be shown in Angular using Ngrx and Reactive Form

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-reactive-forms, angular-directive, date-pipe

I have complex graph and I want to create a reactive with form builder and pass the object in form builder

```js
this.objectForm = this.formBuilder.group({
                    ...this.object
                  });
```

I received the date from back-end in UTC format (e.g. `2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z`). I want to show only the date in `mat-input` field but when user focus out his date and time, both should be saved in store. I don't want to show time to user, but I want it saved in database and Ngrx Store.

Below is the HTML code:

```
<input matInput type="date" formControlName="SelectedDate" name="SelectedDate" id="SelectedDate" 
dateTime>
```

Used different technique e.g. Build custom pipe and custom directive but result is not shown in desired format. **formControlName** (used in above mentioned HTML) accept only string in angular 8 and type='date' only accept date not time.

Below is the code we are trying till now:

```js
import {Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, HostBinding, HostListener, Input, OnChanges, Output, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';
import {NgControl, NgModel} from '@angular/forms';
import {DatePipe, DecimalPipe} from '@angular/common';

@Directive({
  selector: '[dateTime][formControlName]',
})
export class DateTime {


  constructor(private el: ElementRef, public datePipe: DatePipe, private model: NgControl) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.el.nativeElement.value = this.datePipe.transform(this.model.control.value, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    this.model.viewToModelUpdate(this.el.nativeElement.value);
  }


  @HostListener('ngModelChange', ['$event'])
  onModelChange(event) {

  }

  @HostListener('focusout')
  focusOUt() {
    let date: Date = new Date(this.el.nativeElement.value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a fit https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview ?

Comment: Ngrx has problems with saving date (only store primitive types) so store it as a string an convert it to a date in the component

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with loosing the original time (since you're anyway not showing it to the user) I'd just convert it to string during the form creation and then use `(new Date(form.value.SelectedDate)).toUTCString()` to convert it back to full UTC for back-end.

If original time is important, then split the datetime in SelectedDate and SelectedTime. You can then handle SelectedDate separately in you mat-input and on save combine it with SelectedTime before sending back to back-end.